# sql select and insert for items that are connected,but I wanna show them all

Tags: java, c#, sql, sql-server

I have a database that has fields

```
ID,Name,Address,Date
```

I want to insert items with names like Storage1,Storage2,Storage3.When I search them,
if I enter Storage1,I wanna see in my result query Storage1,Storage2,Storage3.If I enter Storage2,I want to see Storage2,Storage1,Storage3.Also for Storage3.

I have an assistant table where I have two id foreign keys,like main_id,and assist id. I have managed to have something like a subgroup.The assistant table looks like this:

```
id id_main assist_id
```

So if I connect Storage2 and Storage3 to Storage1,and I search for Storage1,I get Storage1,Storage2,Storage3.But if I enter Storage2 in the search,I only get Storage2,not Storage1 and Storade3.
How can I connect all 3 items together?
My query for now is

```
SELECT t1.id           AS MainID
 , t1.name            AS MainName
 , t1.address       AS MainAddress
 , t1.date         AS MainDate
 , t2.id           AS SubID
 , t2.name          AS SubName
 , t2.address       AS SubAddress
 , t2.date         AS SubDate
  FROM main_table t1
  JOIN assist_table c ON c.id_main = t1.id
  JOIN main_table t2 ON t2.id = c.id_assist_id
 WHERE t1.name = ?
```

I want it to work for other items to,so maybe beside storage,I would have something like Caffebar1,Caffebar2,Caffebar3.

Comment: Consider creating sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/ and show expected results. So far it is not entirely clear what are you asking. Does your code work? Do you get an error?

Comment: My code works like this.If I select Storage1,it will get me Storage1,Storage2,Storage3.But if I select Storage2,it will show me only Storage2.

In my assist table I have connected Storage2 and 3 to Storage1.

Comment: Do you have the option to add a column? It sounds like you are trying to derive a category from the name. If you made another column to signify a category you could have Storage and Caffebar as FK values you get from a lookup table that you would normalize out.

Comment: thanks,that adding another column solved my problem.it was easy,I just didn't saw it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a SQL question and the java tag should be removed. If you are using java you can consider manipulating it as you retrieve from the resultset.

Alternatively using SQL, you can do something like this.

```
select * from main_table where name = "Storage1" union select * from main_table
```

What the above code does it to first add the results of the storage 1 query followed by the rest. If you want Storage1 to repeat below you can use "UNION ALL" instead of "UNION".

--Reply 1 --

I feel that you are better off creating an additional column on main_table category and use where on it. Otherwise you can try this:

```
select * from main_table where name = "Storage1" union select * from main_table where name like "Storage*"
```

(Don't miss out the asterisk) –

Comment: this would work if in my table i have only storage1,storage2,storage3,I will have types,for example Storage1,Storage2,Storage3,Beach1,Beach2,Beach3,SportArena1,SportArena2,SportArena3...

Comment: I feel that you are better off creating an additional column on main_table category and use where on it. Otherwise you can try this: 
select * from main_table where name = "Storage1" union select * from main_table where name like "Storage*" (Don't miss out the asterisk)

Comment: thank you,adding another column worked,it was simple,I just didn't saw the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd comment, but don't have enough rep yet. It seems like you're missing some records in the assist_table where there should be some id_main values matching storage2 and storage3, not just storage1.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you could get the name without the assist table.

Try this:

> select * from main_table
>   where (name like 'Storage%' or name like 'Caffebar%')

Adding "or name like" for each group of names you would need to search for.

The placement of "%" wildcard will allow a search for the string up to the wildcard, then any combination of characters afterwards.

So for "Storage%", you should get Storage1, Storage2, Storage3, etc.

Comment: I give it an example of storage1,storage2,and storage3.They dont have to have the same name.There can be something like beach,ocean and hotel.And they need to be connected.And when I search for one of those things,if they are connected,I need to see them all in a search query

Comment: you could search for all the names < where name in ('Storage1',Storage2','Caffebar1','Caffebar2')